# how to switch onesignal keys in laravel to send push notifications to different accounts

Tags: php, laravel, onesignal

I have one laravel api for two different apps which has different onesignal keys, I was wondering if it is possible to send a push notification depending on the keys I want to use.

In config/services I have:

```
'onesignal' => [
    'app_id' => env('ONESIGNAL_APP_ID_1'),
    'rest_api_key' => env('ONESIGNAL_REST_API_KEY_1')
],
```

In .env I have the two keys, how can I switch them?

```
ONESIGNAL_APP_ID_1='xxx'
ONESIGNAL_REST_API_KEY_1='xxx'

ONESIGNAL_APP_ID_2='yyy'
ONESIGNAL_REST_API_KEY_2='yyy'
```

Comment: You could try to switch the config config(['onesignal' => ['app_id' => 'foo', 'rest_api_key' => 'bar']) or \Config::set('foo', 'bar'). But it might not work, depending on how the library works.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution from kikutou in github, the solution:

I made two channels and extended to original from onesignal

```
namespace App\Channels;

use Berkayk\OneSignal\OneSignalClient;
use NotificationChannels\OneSignal\OneSignalChannel;

class OneSignalFirstChannel extends OneSignalChannel
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $oneSignal = new OneSignalClient(env("FIRST_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID"), env("FIRST_ONESIGNAL_REST_API_KEY"),null);
        parent::__construct($oneSignal);
    }

}
```

And

```
namespace App\Channels;

use Berkayk\OneSignal\OneSignalClient;
use NotificationChannels\OneSignal\OneSignalChannel;

class OneSignalSecondChannel extends OneSignalChannel
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $oneSignal = new OneSignalClient(env("Second_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID"), env("Second_ONESIGNAL_REST_API_KEY"),null);
        parent::__construct($oneSignal);
    }

}
```

and finally, use the notification

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
        return [OneSignalFirstChannel::class， OneSignalSecondChannel::class];
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other solution that can optimize the use of this as in this case as the number of APP grows will need to replicate it again and again. Is it possible to do by using one channel model and then switch the key by passing a flag?

Answer (score 1):

For those using the "berkayk/laravel-onesignal" package, you can create your own function  that call the package "sendNotificationCustom" function passing in params the "app_id" and "api_key" props. The second app ids you can keep in .env file.

Here an example:

```
  public static function sendToDifferentApp($message, $headings, $tags, $data){

   $contents = array(
       "en" => $message
   );

   $params = array(
       'app_id' => env('ONESIGNAL_SECOND_APP_ID'),
       'contents' => $contents,
       'filters' => $tags,
       'api_key' => env('ONESIGNAL_SECOND_APP_REST_API_KEY'),
   );

   if (isset($data)) {
       $params['data'] = $data;
   }

   if(isset($headings)){
       $params['headings'] = array(
           "en" => $headings
       );
   }

   OneSignal::sendNotificationCustom($params);
```

}